# consulta SELECT, campos relacionados en una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, select, join

Tengo esta view:

el campo `fk_tipo_pollo` esta relacionado con el campo `codigo_producto`, con esto puedo identificar con que código entro al proceso y con que código salió. Entonces lo que quiero lograr es mostrar el `nombre_producto` y `codigo_caja_prodcuto` donde `fk_tipo_pollo` esta relacionado con `codigo_producto` de la misma tabla.

[image: selectunionproductos]

He realizado un INNER JOIN, pero esta aunque me trae los datos similar a los que busco, necesito que traiga incluso los datos que no tiene asignado un `fk_tipo_pollo`, es decir estos campos que están con NULL, son códigos que entran y salen con el mismo **codigo_producto**.

```
SELECT m.codigo_producto,
        m.fecha_registro,
        m.codigo_caja_producto AS codigo_salida,
        m.nombre_producto AS nombre_salidad,
        m.codigo_bolsa_producto,
        m.fk_tipo_pollo,
        e.codigo_caja_producto AS codigo_entro,
        e.nombre_producto AS nombre_entro
FROM codigos_productos as e
INNER JOIN codigos_productos as m ON (m.fk_tipo_pollo = e.codigo_producto)
```

Este es el resultado que estoy obteniendo, pero solo me muestra los campos que `fk_tipo_pollo` tienen asignando un `codigo_producto`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto se hace uniendo las tablas relacionadas con `JOIN`. ¿Has intentado algo? Por otra parte, la imagen no ayuda, mejor muestra la estructura de las tablas implicadas, lo puedes obtener con `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla`.

Comment: Es que el campo **fk_tipo_pollo** esta relacionado con **codigo_producto** en la misma tabla. no sé si me hice entender el resultado que quiero lograr.

Comment: ¿En la misma tabla? ¿Cómo es eso y por qué una tabla tendría una relación en ella misma, no lo entiendo?

Comment: No se si me hice entender, hice un INNER JOIN y estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado, pero esta correcto de este forma?

**SELECT m.codigo_producto,
  m.fecha_registro,
  m.nombre_producto,
  m.codigo_caja_producto,
  m.codigo_bolsa_producto,
  m.fk_tipo_pollo,
  e.nombre_producto
FROM codigos_productos as e
INNER JOIN codigos_productos as m ON (m.fk_tipo_pollo = e.codigo_producto)**

Comment: ¿A qué llamas *correcto*? Te he cuestionado sobre el hecho de que una tabla se relacione con ella misma en dos columnas, ¿puedes explicar lo que justifica eso? ¿Eso no crea datos redundantes? ¿eso no dificulta el mantenimiento? Si es así, deberías normalizar, trasladando cierta información de esa tabla a una nueva tabla. Pero, dado que no explicas el contexto ni muestras la estructura de la tabla, poco podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Te explico hay dos códigos principales: PC02 y PC03, de esos dos códigos se desglosan otros mas códigos. por ejemplo: entro al proceso el producto con el código PC02 pero dentro del proceso salió el código PECH04, entonces los campos **fk_tipo_pollo**  y **codigo_producto** me da la reacción del código con el que entra el producto y del código con el que sale.  Espero haberme hecho entender. Por eso tengo esa relación en la misma tabla. **fk_tipo** seria el código con el que entra, **codigo_producto** código con el que sale.

Comment: No, no se entiende, precisamente la pregunta es para eso, para explicar con claridad el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y explica el contexto, es importante en este tipo de preguntas y son cosas que no dan para explicarlas en un comentario. Es evidente que aquí tienes un problema grave de diseño y si no lo resuelves arrastrarás con él hasta que el programa explote por lentitud, por errores o porque se ha hecho imposible de mantener.

Comment: he modificado la pregunta para entrar un poco mas en contexto.

Comment: Tu diseño es pésimo, debes considerar en normalizar creando por un lado una tabla llamada `producto` donde registres **únicamente** los productos (código, nombre y demás columnas que son parte del producto como entidad única) y otra tabla donde expreses las entradas y salidas de los mismos usando únicamente el código del producto.